# Google Apps Enable SSL Issue

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps

am getting an unclear error , while enabling SSL for custom domain in google apps, i clicked enable billing, and according to new Appengine pricing , 5 Solts of SNI SSL Certificates are free, after enabling ssl, i got the following error

**<--app name here--> has insufficient budget to add additional SSL resources. Increase the application's daily budget to be able to allocate VIPs or SNI certificate slots.**

appengine console says  $0.00 per 5 certificates per month (its free)

i even raised my daily budget to $10 but am still getting the same error, does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Where does it say that enabling SSL slots is free? I have understood that it is paid.

Comment: in google apps security section, its no more paid service, according to new appengine pricing

Comment: @Ramesh were you able to resolve it? What daily budget do you have?

Comment: ya i was able to add it, it was an bug i think

Comment: Today I am getting this error: "Applications should be in good standing and have billing enabled to use SSL.". The billing is enabled, and the daily budget is set to $0.33. The application works fine. ?!??...

Comment: @STF I am getting the same error, I have no idea what it means. Did you get rid of it somehow?

Comment: @Sti: unfortunately, no. Please let me know if you find the solution.

Comment: @STF I got it working. We are apparently using three different services, Google Cloud, Google App Engine, and Google Apps, each with their own billing. I was under the impression that I was paying for Google App Engine through Google Cloud, but that was not the case. On http://appengine.google.com/, selecting the app and going to Billing Status at the bottom of the menu, I noticed that billing wasn't enabled. About 12-15 hours after enabling billing, I was able to add SNI slots in Google Apps. I have never heard of daily budget though, so I don't know if this applies to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try after 24 hours, It ll be resolved .

We face such random issue in google App engine setup/admin panel.